# Can you have a single file with multiple routes in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm new to React/NextJS and I'm trying to figure out if its possible to have a single file with multiple routes.

**Example: Login Page** 
When you request domain.com/login it routes to the auth.js file and shows the related component dynamically instead of having 4 different files/pages. This way the whole page isn’t showing a flash of white when moving between them, it is just dynamically switching the dynamic components area in and out.

Right now I have 4 different files in /pages and you get full page refreshes where the page flashes white and this seems silly.

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just doing something /login?forget-password or /login?confirmation-code, and just do a shallow route change?

Comment: @jamesemanon im new to react but that sounds like a great solution to what I’m thinking! So basically the login.js would be the single page and then you can use ? to load different components?

Comment: yeah, you can have all those perhaps redirect to the login page (remember, you said you were using Next.js).. also, you create a login folder and in that create one file ala. [type].js and the type is now a param and that page is you index.js file that reads the type and displays the appropriate component. A few ways to do it in next.js.